# Asm x64 segfault / Simple program

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, freebsd

I'm writing some small programs in x64 asm, and I have trouble completing this one.
I get a segfault on the scasb instruction. I guess the problem comes from the `mov eax, my_str       ; address of buffer passed to ... ?` line, in the strLen block. I tried with different registers, of course eax is not the right one (32 bits) to use. I'm on FreeBSD, hence the syscall.
Any idea?

Here is the code :

```
 ; 
 ; StrLen.asm : Read a string on stdin and return its length using a strLen replacement
 ; 

 section .data 
 userMsg : 
 db "Please enter a string (max 1024 bytes): ", 0 
 lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg 

 dispMsg : 
 db "Length: ", 0 
 lenDispMsg equ $-dispMsg 

 section .bss ;Uninitialized data 
 my_strLength equ 1024 ; Input buffer size 
 my_str : 
 resb my_strLength ; Input buffer 


 section .text 
 global _start 

 _start: 

 ;;; User Prompt ;;; 
 mov rax, 4 ; write 
 mov rdi, 1 ; stdout 
 mov rsi, userMsg ; msg text 
 mov rdx, lenUserMsg ; msg length 
 syscall 

 ;;; Read and store the string ;;; 
 mov rax, 3            ; read 
 mov rdi, 0            ; stdin 
 mov rsi, my_str       ; address of my_str passed to rsi 
 mov edx, my_strLength ; read n bytes in one go 
 syscall 
 ;mov r9, rax          ; keep sys_read return value (nb of bytes read) 

 ;;; strLen() ;;; 
 mov eax, my_str       ; address of buffer passed to ... ? 
 sub al, al            ; zeroes al 
 not rcx               ; 1/ecx = ecx highest value 
 cld                   ; clear direction flag for byte search 
 repne scasb           ; repeat byte search until match 
 not rcx               ; ecx contains 1/length +1 
 dec rcx               ; -1 & ok we have the length 

 ;;; Write back the length ;;; 
 mov rax, rdi          ; write 
 mov rdi, 1            ; stdout 
 ; mov rcx, rcx        ; nb bytes read 
 mov rdx, my_strLength 
 syscall 

 ;;; Exit ;;; 
 mov rax, 1            ; exit 
 xor rdi, rdi          ; return value 
 syscall
```

Comment: You can read a reference on `SCASB` : the register to use is `RDI`. Also, where do you set `RCX` before `REPNE` ?

Comment: As @ElderBug pointed out, the address of the buffer for `scasb` should go into `rdi`, not `rax`. Even if that hadn't been the case, you're clearing the least significant byte of `rax` on the very next line by doing `sub al, al`. You need to be aware of how every single instruction alters the values of the registers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not with my FreeBSD box right now but I tried with RDI it resulted in "unknown syscall" if I'm not mistaken.

al is needed by scasb, that's why it is cleared. Thanks for pointing that out, you're right RAX is a dumb choice

And you're right ElderBug I overlooked the rpne prefix....

Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Well, this also looks wrong: `mov rax, rdi          ; write `

Comment: Since `sys_read` doesn't return a zero-terminated string, scasb isn't going to find a zero in any case. `rax` will return stringlength (+ 1) in `rax` so you don't need it.

Comment: Uhh.. yes it should be 4, sys_write, sorry this is a typo

Comment: @Frank Kolter : Yes I'm aware I can get the length by the sys_read, but the scope is more the strLen block. So I should append a /0 at the end of the input string before search?

Comment: Thanks everybody, your insights are useful and appreciated